# Upload recorded audio file in Objective-C using PHP

Tags: ios, audio, upload, avfoundation

I am trying to record an audio file in my app, then I want to upload to a web server, 
the code i have written is working for recording and playback and even for uploading to the web server using PHP, the only issues that I am facing that the uploaded file is always blank, ZERO file size

Can you please have a look at my code and let me know what am i doing incorrectly to cause this issue

Everything below is working perfectly, the only piece that I struggling with the when the file uploaded it appears in the destination folder of the server, but of ZERO file size, I am also attaching my php at the end of the post.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
    [btnStop setEnabled:NO];
    [btnPlay setEnabled:NO];

    // Set the audio file
    NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject], @"MyAudioMemo.m4a", nil];
    //NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
    outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

    // Setup audio session
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];

    // Define the recorder setting
    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    // Initiate and prepare the recorder
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:nil];
    recorder.delegate = self;
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
    [recorder prepareToRecord];

}

- (IBAction)record:(id)sender {
    // Stop the audio player before recording
    if (player.playing) {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording) {
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [session setActive:YES error:nil];

        // Start recording
        [recorder record];
        [btnRecord setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        // Pause recording
        [recorder pause];
        [btnRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [btnStop setEnabled:YES];
    [btnPlay setEnabled:NO];
}

- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    [recorder stop];

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
}

- (IBAction)play:(id)sender {
    if (!recorder.recording){
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

- (IBAction)upload:(id)sender {
    NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[recorder.url absoluteString]];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://mydomain.com/phpcodes/uploadFile.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"AudioFile3.m4a\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:file1Data]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Return String= %@",returnString);
}

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully (BOOL)flag{
    [btnRecord setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnStop setEnabled:NO];
    [btnPlay setEnabled:YES];
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done"
                                                    message: @"Finish playing the recording!"
                                                   delegate: nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

PHP Code

```
    <?php
        $folder = "audio/";

        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))  {   
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $folder.$_FILES['userfile']['name'])) {
            Echo "File uploaded";
        } else {
            Echo "File not moved to destination folder. Check permissions";
        };
        } else {
            Echo "File is not uploaded.";
        }; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Please learn how to format your question properly.  Have you seen it?

Comment: Sorry for that, I think it looks good now.

Comment: Much better!  Thanks!

Comment: Also, don't post so much code. Narrow your issue down a bit and only post the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the problem is with this line:

```
NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[recorder.url absoluteString]];
```

The `initWithContentsOfFile:` method expects a file path but you are passing in the string representing of a file URL.

Try this:

```
NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[recorder.url path]];
```

or:

```
NSData *file1Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url];
```

Use of the debugger will help with this issue. Set a breakpoint in `upload:` method and check the value of each variable. Most likely you will see that `file1Data` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this alternate solution:

```
NSData *mediaContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:_mediaURL.absoluteString];
```